# Grouped percent change in R data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'd like to calculate the % diff in subsequent observations of an R `data.table`, grouping by a variable. For example, given a dataset like this:

```
dt <- data.table(group=c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3)),
                 index=rep(1:3, 2),
                 val=1:6)
#    group index val
# 1:     A     1   1
# 2:     A     2   2
# 3:     A     3   3
# 4:     B     1   4
# 5:     B     2   5
# 6:     B     3   6
```

I'd like a result like this, calculating % diff of `val` (first record goes from 1->2, so 100%, second 2->3 so 50% diff, etc.):

```
#    group index pct.diff
# 1:     A     1     1.00
# 2:     A     2     0.50
# 3:     B     1     0.25
# 4:     B     2     0.20
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `diff` and `.N` to remove the final record in each group:

```
dt[, list(index=index[-.N],
          pct.diff=diff(val) / val[-.N]),
   group]
```

This produces the result at the bottom of the question.